# Can we see "imaginary" light beams?

Tags: optics, interference, geometric-optics, superposition, hologram

When a reference beam, R, interferes with an object beam, O, the interference pattern is captured by a holographic plate. When reconstructing the image, the reference beam is incident on the holographic plate and the outputted light, I_plate,  can be described by the following equation

[image]

First term: The reference beam, travelling in the direction shown

Second term: The object beam (I know this is a virtual image but how is this described by the equation?)

Third term: The complex conjugate of the object beam (what do I see in real life that represents this part of the equation?)

(all outputted beams have some altered amplitude/intensity)

The following diagram is what I think the interaction looks like from the equation, however I know the directions aren't correct.

[image]

Comment: the 2nd term is an "expanding" beam since it is proportional to $O$, you cannot "see" it unless it is focused. The 3rd term is proportional to $O^*$ hence it is converging, it makes an image. Think of a point source, emits expanding radial waves $O$, when focussed the waves converge to a point backwards and are like $O^*$

Comment: @hyportnex thanks so much! Do you have any sources that you can link me to for further reading?

Comment: many years ago when I read them I found both these books marvellous https://www.amazon.com/Lasers-Holography-Dover-Explaining-Science-ebook/dp/B00A4205TU/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1521406300&sr=8-1&keywords=kock+holography and  https://www.amazon.com/Fundamentals-Holography-Yu-N-Denisyuk/dp/B000SAH8UW/ref=sr_1_2?s=digital-text&ie=UTF8&qid=1521406352&sr=8-2&keywords=denisyuk+holography